# Iterating through all of a doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, iteration

I'm reading through a file and adding each line to a Doubly Linked List that I have, and I'm not sure how to include the last line of the file, and just hard-coded the last line. Is there a better way to do this?

(sc is a Scanner, s is the next String)

```
while(sc.hasNext()){
    if(s.trim().compareTo("") != 0)
        _list.addAtEnd(s);
    s = sc.nextLine();
}
_list.addAtEnd("A D 10");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop to first read the line and then add it :

```
while(sc.hasNext()){
    s = sc.nextLine();
    if(s.trim().compareTo("") != 0)
        _list.addAtEnd(s);
}
```

If you have the first `s = sc.nextLine()` before the loop, remove it.